# Return a list in a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

I would like to return a list of String in my FutureBuilder but it is impossible for me because an error tells me that the  lists are not a subtype of the Widget type.
Indeed the return must be of type List to be able to add it to the initialization of my list in my class in my main class
I am attaching the two classes to you as well as the error message so that you can understand.
Thank you

Class READCITEE

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReadCitee extends StatelessWidget {
  final String docCityId;

  ReadCitee(this.docCityId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference cities = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('city');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: cities.doc(docCityId).get(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Something went wrong");
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            return Text("Documents does not exist");
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            var data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return (data["Nom"]);
          }
          return Text("Loading");
        });
  }
}
```

CLASSE PRINCIPALE

```
import 'package:ampc93/fonction/firebase_crud/add_citee.dart';
import 'package:ampc93/fonction/firebase_crud/read_citee.dart';
import 'package:ampc93/page_citee.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageVille extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? titre;

  PageVille(this.titre);

  @override
  _PageVilleState createState() => _PageVilleState();
}

class _PageVilleState extends State<PageVille> {
  TextEditingController citeeController = TextEditingController();

  List<dynamic> citeesList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    citeesList.add(ReadCitee(widget.titre!));
  }

  Future<void> displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: TextField(
              controller: citeeController,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(hintText: "Entrez une nouvelle citée"),
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    AddCitee(widget.titre!, citeeController.text);
                    setState(() {
                      citeesList.add(citeeController.text);
                      citeeController.clear();
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  citeeController.clear();
                },
                child: Text("Annuler"),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.titre!),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: citeesList[index],
                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                PageCitee(citeesList[index]))),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                        color: Colors.red[300],
                        iconSize: 32,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            citeesList.remove(citeesList[index]);
                          });
                        }));
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: citeesList.length)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => displayDialog(context),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>#b2e48):
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>
package:ampc93/…/firebase_crud/read_citee.dart:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      ReadCitee.build.<anonymous closure>
package:ampc93/…/firebase_crud/read_citee.dart:23
#1      _FutureBuilderState.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:773
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4612
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4495
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4667
...
```

Comment: In the third if statement, you are returning data['Nom'] which is of type List and futureBuilder cant build List. So you should instead return a widget there like return Text(data['Nom'][0].toString())....
Also in every other return statement you can see that you have returned a widget i.e Text()

Comment: Precisely @Daniyal in the third "if", I don't want to return a widget type object but a list

Comment: thats what the error is...It is expecting a return type of widget but you are returning List...by the way why you want to return list?

Comment: I want to return a list because in my main class I created a list that I complete from the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the "DocumentSnapshot". Because apparently, the "FutureBuilder" are expecting "DocumentSnapshot" data type. Try remove that from the "Future Builder" and see what happens.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not change the type of my error which always tells me that returning a list is not possible because a list is not a subtype of Widget type